# Tourist Visa for Italy for Canadians

Tags: visas, schengen, canadian-citizens, tourist-visas

I have a Canadian passport but live in the United Arab Emirates. I would like to visit Italy for a week but would like to know if my passport will be enough or if I will need a tourist visa.

Comment: I think the fact of you living in the UAE is irrelative to your case, the passport is what matters, hence I removed the tag for it and edited the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Italy is part of the Schengen zone, and if you are presenting a Canadian passport, a visa is not required beforehand.

Canada is mentioned explicitly in Annex II of  **COUNCIL REGULATION (EC) No 539/2001** of 15 March 2001: listing the third countries whose nationals must be in possession of visas when crossing the external borders and those whose nationals are exempt from that requirement.

http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CONSLEG:2001R0539:20091219:EN:PDF

Your current residence and circumstances (if not pejorative or suspicious) have no bearing on it.